# BeautifulSoup: Merge tables and export to .csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I have been trying to download data from different urls and then save it to a csv file.

The idea is extract Annual / Quarterly data from:
*https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/MMM/financials/*

**Annual:**

https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/MMM/financials/cash-flow

[image]

**Quarter**:

https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/MMM/financials/cash-flow/quarter

[image: Quarter]

With the following code:

```
 import requests
 import pandas as pd
    
    urls = ['https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/AAPL/financials/cash-flow',
            'https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/MMM/financials/cash-flow']
    
    
    def main(urls):
        with requests.Session() as req:
            goal = []
            for url in urls:
                r = req.get(url)
                df = pd.read_html(
                    r.content, match="Cash Dividends Paid - Total")[0].iloc[[0], 0:3]
                goal.append(df)
            new = pd.concat(goal)
            print(new)
    
    
    main(urls)
```

Output:
[image: output]

I can extract the desired information (in the example Annual **2015** and **2016** for **2 firms**) but just for 1 set (quarter or annual)

I would like to **merge** the tables Annual + Quarter

For that I thought in this code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

html = urlopen('https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/MMM/financials/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

ids = ['cash-flow','cash-flow/quarter']


with open("news.csv", "w", newline="", encoding='utf-8') as f_news:
    csv_news = csv.writer(f_news)
    csv_news.writerow(["A"])

    for id in ids:
      a = soup.find("Cash Dividends Paid - Total", id=id)
      csv_news.writerow([a.text])
```

But In getting the following error:

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup elements do not have a property `text`, but a method `get_text()`

```
  csv_news.writerow([a.get_text()])
```

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text

Answer (score 1):

It means your `soup.find()` didn't find the element you want. `a` is `None`.

Why do you need an `id`? I checked the annual page as May, 19th. There is no need to use `id`.